# Positioning elements like a table, without using the table tag

Tags: html, css, position

I am trying to position some stuff in 3 columns. The first column has an icon, 2nd column has text, and the 3rd column has an image.

I wish to do this without using the Table tag. Using CSS I have gotten the first 2 columns placed correctly, here is an image:

[image: What I got so far...]

On the right, I need to add another image, without disturbing the text on the left.

This is my HTML code (stripped down to the basics):

```
            <img src="Images/icon-1.png" /> 
            <span class="content-title">My title 1</span> 
            <p>
            Here is my text ...
            </p>
            <br />


            <img src="Images/Icon-2.png" /> 
            <span class="content-title">My Title 2</span> 
            <p>
            Here is my text ...
            </p>
            <br />
```

And the CSS that emulates the table layout:

```
.content-title
{
    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #363636;
    top: -28px;
    position:relative;
    left:+10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#content-benefits p
{
    margin-left:80px;
    top:-30px;
    position:relative;
    width:325px;
}
```

My issue is, that I can't figure out how to place my image on the right, without making it's `position:absolute;`, but if I do that, I have to (AFAIK) use JavaScript to place the images relatively to their corresponding paragraphs.

Comment: is it appropriate to use `float:right`?

Comment: can you try with float attribute in css or in any tag define in style you can put content on right or left like wise float:right | float:left

Comment: @thirtydot - on the far right, where all the whitespace is. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want another image add it to the HTML before the rest of the "section" and then float it right with:

```
img {
   float: right;
}
```

On another note, why aren't you using heading tags to display your headings?

Comment: Using Float:right; and adjusting the right margin did the trick - the key was to place the right-most image below the title and before the paragraph.

Comment: This will get the mark because it only requires 2 lines in the CSS. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the css `display:table` to make it apear using a table take a look at the docs for this found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Place the image after the titles span end tag

```
<img src="Images/icon-1.png" /> 
            <span class="content-title">My title 1</span> 
<img src="Images/icon-1.png" /> 
            <p>
            Here is my text ...
            </p>
            <br />
```

Answer (score 1):

if i properly understand your layout i would do this

```
<img style="float:left; width:80px" src="image/icon-1.png"/>
<div style="width:405px">
  <img style="float:right; width:80px"/>
  <div style="float:left; width:325px">
    <span/>
    <p>
    ...
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

you wont need the other positioning you used

if you cannot change the markup,
than put `width` to the `span` and `p` and `float:left`, and put `float:right` and `width` to `img`

putting `float` automatically converts the element to `display:inline-block` which mean that it no longer distributes to the free page width, but takes the minimal allowed space (set by `width`) and stays rectangular. This way it becomes something like a column.